# Display text in one line and remove border which covering the text

Tags: html, css

please visit [link](http://vikas.collagekingapp.com/zephyr-mechanix-nx0-small.html) & click on "Buy Now" button.

than you can see this image :

[image]

using CTRL + F, search for "**Check Delivery**" text. you can see 2 texts.

text which is present below is fine. but in above

i want to remove the outer box covering these texts.

i can use `border-width : 0px 0px 0px`

but it will hide the box which is present in **right-bottom** also.  i want to hide only box present inside table.

```
border-color: #565656 #ccc #ccc;
border-image: none;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 3px 1px 1px;
box-sizing: border-box;
min-height: auto;
padding: 10px 20px 25px;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know your HTML-structure but I assume, that your upper "Check Delivery Box" is in an DIV or SECTION (or whatever) with the same ID/CLASS than for example the lower "Check Delivery Box".

And to this DIV/SECTION/"ID"/"CLASS" you apply this Borders in your CSS.

When you change the ID or the tag, this should remove the box.

Comment: i checked it , both are in different div

Comment: please help me here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37545936/display-background-color-for-the-page-align-texts-at-center

Answer (score 1):

Remove the Padding of your

```
 <div class = 'shipping'>
```

And style individual elements, and the table practice that you are following is not recommended practice.

Comment: i gave padding : 0 0 0 px, than its looking like this : http://prntscr.com/adewac

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this?

```
 table .shipping-form {border-width : 0px 0px 0px;}
```